# MS/Word Hidden Text and a Template

Tags: microsoft-word

I found a template for EDI specifiations and have been using it. 
Today, I clicked something or did some keystroke by accident that seems to have revealed hidden text that is in red (that I never saw before), and I saved the file.

I have included a sample below.
Now I would like to go back to the way it was before where this text was hidden.

[image]

The red text doesn't seem to use any special style. I was thinking this might be some feature of templates that I've never seen before.

I checked a backup of my file, and thought it was okay.  But then when I clicked "Enabled Editing", the red text appeared again.  So maybe it was there all along.  I'd just like to be sure there isn't some secret I'm not familiar with for templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the "Show/Hide ¶" button. In addition to showing/hiding formatting symbols, that will also show/hide hidden text.

And if you want to mark/unmark a selection of text as hidden, that's under the Font settings. Select the text, right-click, and choose Font. Then check or uncheck the "Hidden" checkbox under the Effects section.

Comment: Generally, hidden text (when displayed) is indicated by the dotted underline (as your image shows).  You can select whether hidden text is displayed in the Display Options.